# Pub/Sub message to database record load pattern - change data capture questions?

Tags: database, etl, integration, message-queue, publish-subscribe

An existing operational data store that was fed from an ETL process needs to change to receive data as messages published to a queue.  We need to use middleware (SnapLogic) to subscribe to a queue of JSON messages that will contain aggregates of that contain data spanning 15 tables. Some of the data in the JSON messages will be require records in the target database but others will be data already exists but are needed to create a full aggregate message.

This seems like a common pattern, but I've not found any good discussions of the complexities online, particularly about dealing with 'change data capture' issues.  For example, should the publisher mark record as insert, update etc if elements message are changes so that the middleware can minimise the transactions hitting the DB? Or is this an anti-pattern, the publisher shouldn't tell consumers what to do with the data?  Should the middleware manage the identification of changes, and if so, should it query the target for every insert / update to see in there is a change?

I'm currently thinking about the design of the JSON messages that the middleware and other consumers will subscribe to.